# What is causing my error in executing arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe from Keil uVision?

Tags: stm32, arm, keil

I'm attempting to set up Keil uVision to build a simple C++ program for the STM32F3 microcontroller. I've downloaded the GNU ARM toolchain on my Windows computer and placed it into the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\bin\`. In Keil, I created a project and opened a window Manage Project Items where I was able to select `Use GCC Compiler (GNU) for ARM projects` and specified the prefix `arm-none-eabi-`.

When I click Build, the output window shows that it finishes compiling and reaches the linking stage. Here's the output:

`Rebuild target 'Target 1'
linking...
--- Error: failed to execute 'arm-none-eabi-gcc'
".\evt-bms.elf" - 1 Error(s), 0 Warning(s).
Target not created.
Build Time Elapsed:  00:00:00`

I've verified that arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe is in the bin directory (though I'd be expecting a complaint about g++ since it's a C++ source).

Here's a screenshot of the Folders/Extensions settings page:
[image: Folders/Extensions settings screenshot]

Does anyone have any ideas for further debugging I can do? It'd be great if the output window had a little more information, as it really isn't all that helpful by just saying it couldn't run it without any context of the command it attempted.

Comment: C++ code needs to be linked with the `…-g++` compiler driver, because the linker cannot tell from the `.o` files that these used to be C++, so linking with `…-gcc` will not link correctly. There should be a setting somewhere to select how to call the linker, but I don't have a current installation, so I cannot check.

Comment: Try running the identical command line from a terminal, to see what the compiler says directly. (You can add -v or --verbose for more information)

Comment: @BrianDrummond unfortunately I can't even see what command was run that triggered that. The output I posted was the result of clicking the Build or Rebuild buttons.

Comment: There will be some way to get that command line - buried deep in the documentation, no doubt.

Answer (score 1):

I use Keil µVision, too (didn't even know you can set the GNU compiler)

I installed the "GNU Tools ARM Embedded\6 2017-q2-update" and Keil automatically filled the path - but without the leading /bin/ as seen in your screenshot. Maybe try removing it? (e.g. my path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\6 2017-q2-update\")